# What geological structure(s) is responsible for the recent Queensland earthquakes?

Tags: seismology, earthquakes, intraplate

Recently, south-east Queensland has been rattled by 2 moderate earthquakes - a 5.3 a couple of days ago ([News report](http://www.goldcoastbulletin.com.au/news/gold-coast/magnitude-earthquake-rocks-queensland-buildings-shaken-on-the-gold-coast/story-fnj94idh-1227462846220)) and a 5.7 tremor just a few hours ago as of writing this post ([News Report](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-08-01/second-earthquake-in-two-days-felt-in-south-east-queensland/6665546)). These are significant as they are the strongest earthquakes experienced in Queensland.

The location of the earthquakes and their associated aftershocks are shown in the map from the Geoscience Australia [Earthquake map](http://www.ga.gov.au/earthquakes/recentQuakes.do?when=1&where=2&which=false&x=46&y=6):

[image]

Now, I understand that these are intraplate earthquakes, but my question is,

**What geological structure(s) have caused these recent earthquakes?**